# Linking with both static and dynamic libraries in MSVC

Tags: c++, linker, visual-c++

I am working on a c++ project that links to a static library. However, I want to use intel's TBB, which is only available as a dynamic library. I tried to set this up in visual studio but I can't get it to work. Does anyone have detailed directions to do this if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically when a library is made available as a dynamic library (.dll), it also comes with a .lib file to link against (as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552248/dll-question-load-time-dynamic-linking-and-run-time-dynamic-linking/552281)). This can be added to the project's list of inputs the same way that a static library is

> Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies (in VS2008)

If a .lib is not available, then you'll have to load the .dll at runtime using Win32 API function [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179(VS.85).aspx) and then subsequent calls to [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) to get the addresses of the functions you need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about linking to a RUNTIME library?  No you can only link to one.  You have to either change your project, or you have to recompile the TBB to link to static runtime as well.