# Linking static and dynamic libraries in same visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am trying to link static and dynamic libraries in the same project in visual studio 2019. The thing is:

- In **project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation**, when I select MT for Runtime library, my dynamic library creates a *problem mismatch detected for runtimeLibrary: value MD_DynamicRelease doesn't match value MT_StaticRelease.*
- In **project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation**, when I select MD for Runtime library, my static library creates the same problem

I have read other posts like [Linking with both static and dynamic libraries in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009098/linking-with-both-static-and-dynamic-libraries-in-msvc) but there is no explanation on how to link both statically and dynamically in the project.
Could you please explain me how I can proceed?

Comment: You will need to create 2 new configurations (for total of 4).  And set the runtime library and debug/release options in each one. So you will end up with 4 builds in total /MTd, /MT, /MDd, /MD, etc.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: `Build > Configuration Manager ...` Open the Active solution configurations dropdown and click `<New..>` fill in the configuration details.

Comment: But at then end, I want only one .exe in release. What you propose is to make two different builds. My goal is, in one executable to have some libraries that are dynamically linked and other that are statically linked?

Comment: Why are you trying to link with both the static and dynamic runtime libraries?  You need to choose one or the other.

Comment: Because I have some libraries that can only be linked dynamically, for legal reasons and other that I have to link statically

Comment: You can't mix both in the same build, as you will get multiple instances of the runtime support library.

Comment: Arf... Is it specific to visual studio? In QT creator, it is possible

Comment: It is undefined behavior to mix and match runtimes on windows. Your program may appear to work but end up crashing or randomly giving you the wrong result.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm What if Vendor 1 providing X functionality provides a static library while Vendor 2 providing Y functionality provides a dynamic library and you need to have both functionalities in the same project?

Comment: @RichardCritten There could very well be situations where one needs to statically link with one library (because the vendor has provided only static libraries), while another vendor who provides a different functionality has only provided dll files. Certainly, such situations are quite common, I would imagine when your application needs both functionalities.

Comment: @Tryer and MS says this is not possible ie talk to your vendor.

Comment: @RichardCritten I created a simple github repo with only source code and .vcxproj files from the online MS tutorial on how to create and use static and dynamil linked libraries. I have the same client app link to both the dll as well as the static lib. https://github.com/TryerGit/link_static_dynamic_together
When you get a chance, and if and when you feel like it, do clone it and run the .sln solution file. Everything is setup so that it pulls in the appropriate projects (3 in total - client, dll, static library).It compiles and runs perfectly fine! Perhaps we are talking of different things?