# is Windows Explorer created in a high level language?

Tags: c#, windows-explorer

I wanted to know if windows explorer is created like in C# using ListView and other components, is it like that ?

Comment: I highly doubt it - although the gui could be, the underlying code will not be

Comment: Windows explorer has been around far longer than .NET. But C is also considered a high-level language, so the answer to the title would be "yes".

Comment: I think your question probably is related to know in which language windows is written? isn't it

Comment: @Sachin - I can't remember Windows 3.1 having the windows explorer

Comment: @harold how do you know which compiler was used to build explorer?

Comment: Windows Explorer is a native Win32 application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to open explorer.exe and see if it has dependencies on any .NET assembly, and you will find that it does not.

Here's the output from my machine (Windows 7 x64):

[image: Windows 7 x64 explorer.exe dependencies]

As you can see there is no dependency to `mscoree.dll`, which is a [dead giveaway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545603/is-mscorlib-dll-mscoree-dll-loaded-when-net-application-runs) that explorer.exe has nothing to do with .NET.

Comment: +1 - I thought I was the only one that still had to use gdi32