# What is the application of dynamic loading in c programming?

Tags: c, dynamic, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dynamic-library

In witch situation we need to use dynamic loading instead of dynamic linking? In advanced linux programming I read that it used for writing plugins, any one could explain more?

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052464/difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking

Comment: see also: [Difference between load-time dynamic linking and run-time dynamic linking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2055840)

Comment: @Mike my question is different from this.

Comment: On most platforms, dynamic linking *uses* dynamic loading, but not explicitly in your code. Your system's loader uses dynamic loading to resolve dynamic link dependencies.

Comment: Not a good question for SO, there are too many answers and many will be a matter of opinion or aesthetics. It's like asking how many recipes should I use butter in, instead of margarine.